# What are the security implications of uploading files from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser, websecurity

Suppose I have a drawing html application that my users can use in their web pages. They include the widget setting its src in an iframe (with their generated key passed as query string), I send it with a [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) header to restrict use to their domain and their users can use the widget to draw.

Now suppose they want to load drawings saved on their servers and pass them to my iframe widget, and they want users to click a button (on their site) to save the current drawing on their server. In both cases, they can send a message to my iframe specifying a signed url, and my iframe can listen to the event and use `fetch` to, respectively, download or upload the desidered asset.

What are the security implications of my iframe downloading or uploading on their behalf? Is this setup solid or can it be abused? If it can be abused, how?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of downloading and uploading , but it is possible to share/pass messages to and from iframe.

More details here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Security concerns

If you do not expect to receive messages from other sites, do not add any event listeners for message events. This is a completely foolproof way to avoid security problems.

If you do expect to receive messages from other sites, always verify the sender's identity using the origin and possibly source properties. Any window (including, for example, http://evil.example.com) can send a message to any other window, and you have no guarantees that an unknown sender will not send malicious messages. Having verified identity, however, you still should always verify the syntax of the received message. Otherwise, a security hole in the site you trusted to send only trusted messages could then open a cross-site scripting hole in your site.

Always specify an exact target origin, not *, when you use postMessage to send data to other windows. A malicious site can change the location of the window without your knowledge, and therefore it can intercept the data sent using postMessage.